# Java Assertion Exception

Tags: java, exception

I've made s simple program to let the user withdraw a certain amount out of a bank account, and if they withdraw too much it will cause an AssertionError, how do I get it to write out the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Withdraw {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

        int t = 10000;
        System.out.println("Withdraw or Deposit");
        String in = a.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your value");
        int wd = a.nextInt();

        if(in.equals("withdraw")){
            int b;
            b = t - wd;
            System.out.println(t);
            if (b < 0){
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`assert` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by `write out the error`, it can mean a few different things. Please clarify what input are you entering, what response you expect, and what response are you receiving instead

Comment: Are you sure you want to work with assertions? Those are usually disabled at runtime and only intended for consistency checks during development. Not for something like user input validation.

Comment: @GregHewgill i know what it is but not how to use it correctly

Comment: @Hamy I'd like it to write the balance out in the account along with something i write for it

Comment: @Thilo yes my assignment needs it to have an assertion error occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you want your `AssertionError` to include some information on the balance. You're using the constructor `AssertionError()`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html), you can also use the constructor `AssertionError(Object detailMessage)` where the object will be converted to a string. So you can do this:

```
throw new AssertionError("Oh no, your balance " + b + " is negative!");
```

PS - Your two `if` statements have different spacing e.g. `if(` versus `if (`. This is an example of "code smell" - not a true error, but poor style indicating carelessness. Try to keep these little things consistent going forward and your code will look cleaner and more readable

Comment: thats exactly what i needed thanks, I have issues setting up these exceptions to actually print things i want them to.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if block containing throw with:

```
assert b>0 : "Invalid Assertion, b must be positive"
```

The String message can be whatever you want. But this is only useful if you run your program as

```
java -ea ClassName
```

If you want to throw error in normal java runtime environment, don't use AssertionError. It is meant for the `assert` statement. Throw a custom exception, or use some exception class's `Exception(String message)`
constructor.